# Two preloaders of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing animation in javascript/jquery+html and the code looks something like this (simplify version).

- html:

  ```
  <div id="animationList">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Testing animation 1</div>
        <div class="resolutionRow">
          <span>execute</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Testing animation 2</div>
        <div class="resolutionRow">
          <span>execute</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="statusBar">
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="animation"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- javascript:

  ```
  var imgCount[0]=30; //number of images for Testing animation 1
  var imgCount[1]=1000; //number of images for Testing animation 2
  var progressWidth=0; //default progressbar width
  var imgArray=new Array(); //array which will hold image sources strings
  var checkProgress;
  var goAnim;

  //if user choose an animation
  $('#animationList li span').click(function() {
    //need to stop older animation
    if(goAnim) clearInterval(goAnim);
    //ensure just one checkProgress interval is running (doesn't work)
    if(checkProgress) clearInterval(checkProgress);
    //get animation id
    animId=$(this).parent().parent().index();
    //call index function
    start();
  });

  function start() {
    //clear array with image sources
    if(imgArray.length>0) imgArray.length=0;
    //check progress status
    checkProgress=setInterval(checkProgWidth,10);
    //execute images preloader
    loadImageset(1);
  };

  //check progress percentage
  function checkProgWidth() {
    //start animation after progress percentage is 100 (if all images are loaded)
    if(progressWidth==100) {
      clearInterval(checkProgress); //stop this function
      goAnim=setInterval(animation,1000); //execute interval for animation function (won't write it here, it's not important)
    }
  };

  //preload images to browser's cache
  function loadImageset(i) {
    //merge img source
    imgSrc=animId+'/'+i+'.jpg';
    //create image object
    var imgCaching=new Image();
    //fill image object source
    imgCaching.src=imgSrc;
    //insert image source into array
    imgArray[i]=imgSrc;
      //do this stuff after image is loaded
      imgCaching.onload=function() {
        //count progress percentage
        progressWidth=Math.round((i/imgCount)*100);
        //set css of preloader div
        $('#statusBar').css({
          width:progressWidth+'%',
          backgroundColor:'#fff'
        });
        $('#statusBar').text(progressWidth+'%');
        //load next image...
        if(i<=imgCount[animId]) {
          i++;
          loadImageset(i);
        }
        //...or return
        else return;
      };
  };
  ```

Point is that I have one div with list of animations and in other div is container for animation (animation=changing the background-image of this container). Click on some of span from first div executes the animation, it means load images to browser's cache and while images are loading there is an interval function checkProgWidth() which counts the progress percentage -> if it's equal to 100 (all images are loaded) then stop the interval and start the animation.

Demo on http://hlavsene.sav.sk/test/sos.

Problems:

1.) When images of one animation are loading (when progressbar is in move) and during that I choose (click on) the same or another animation I need to stop the loading images of first animation and start the loading of the second one. But I can't do that. You can see it on animation 3 and 4 (they have a lot of images so the loading is long) on the demo site. The progressbar starts to going mad, I think browser starts to load images from the both of animations, it means it doesn't stop loading images from the first animation. Or maybe there is another problem.. Do you have any advice what should I do?

2.) Sometimes there is a blink between changing images, sometimes not. Do u know why?

I'll really appreciate any help. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

1) there's no reliable and guaranteed way for stopping loading images once you said the browser to start the download.
A workaround is to download them with AJAX, and once downloaded re-download (they will actually be taken from the browser's cache) by setting img src

Additionally you should probably keep a kind of animation object, and a way to stop it from at least altering the 'canvas', something like

```
animation = {
  stopped: false,
  start: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
      if (!this.stopped) {...}
      else return;
    }  
  },
  stop: function () {this.stopped = true;}
}
```